# Adding a progress bar to gdal.Translate()

Tags: python-3.x, gdal

Similar to [Adding Progress Bar to gdal.Warp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183923/adding-progress-bar-to-gdal-warp) but for python 3. How to add a progress bar to `gdal.Translate()` in a python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out theres a callback function provided with the `gdal` python bindings called `TermProgress_nocb`.

Example:

```
# gdal_translate with progressbar
_ = gdal.Translate(
    *args, 
    callback=gdal.TermProgress_nocb,
    **kwargs,
)

# Write output to disc
_ = None
```

Prints:

```
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

I discovered this while exploring `osgeo_utils.auxiliary`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def progress_cb(complete, message, cb_data):
    '''Emit progress report in numbers for 10% intervals and dots for 3%'''
    if int(complete*100) % 10 == 0:
        print(f'{complete*100:.0f}', end='', flush=True)
    elif int(complete*100) % 3 == 0:
        print(f'{cb_data}', end='', flush=True)

gdal.Translate(outfile, infile, creationOptions=options,
    callback=progress_cb,
    callback_data='.')
```

Results:

```
$ my-gdal-translate.py
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
```

Modelled after https://github.com/postmates/gdal/blob/master/scripts/gdalimport.py.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging I realised my earlier conclusion was wrong. What's actually happening is that the callback function may be disabled if you have used the SQLStatement= or where= arguments, which are specific to gdal.VectorTranslate().
The -progress argument is added automatically to your call to Translate or VectorTranslate if you provide a callback function.

Comment: Thanks Sem! that's good to know. It would be helpful if you could add a short reproducible snippet to your answer.